# How to copy Mathematica settings from Linux to Windows

Tags: formatting, files-and-directories, windows, linux, configuration

I have installed Mathematica both in Windows and in Linux. Can I copy the \$UserBaseDirectory folder in Linux (usually `~/.Mathematica`) to the \$UserBaseDirectory in Windows?

Do they have the same content? Should I copy something more to make the settings I have in Linux apply properly to the Windows version?

---

EDIT: Okay, I realised the content of the configuration files have many Linux-style paths, so it is probably not advisable to just paste the folder in Windows.

How can I transfer these configurations then?

Comment: Not sure there is an easy solution, but technically you can always write some code that parses the explicit filenames and transforms them for Windows :)

Comment: Hum ok. I guess I'll just copy paste the appropriate configs from the Option Inspector into the Windows version.